# Obtain EditText string with Espresso

Tags: android, junit4, android-espresso

I am trying to automate some tests with Espresso. I can not find a way to get the string of an EditText element. I have tried `onView(withId(R.id.edit_message)).toString()` but it does not work. I cant seem to save the EditText element into a variable.

Here is my test activity.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)

public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

 @Rule
      public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);


@Test
public void testString(){
    EditText et = (EditText) onView(withId(R.id.edit_message));
        String edit = et.getText().toString();

        onView(withId(R.id.edit_message)).perform(typeText("Hello World!"));
        onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click());

        String text = onView(withId(R.id.text_view)).toString();
        Log.d("THE TEXT TYPED IS:",edit);
        Log.d("THE TEXT RETURNED IS:",text);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying this `onView(allOf(withId(android.R.id.message))).check(matches(withText("Hello!")));`?

Comment: Didnt try that, gonna try now. Does that line replaces the assert from JUnit?

Comment: Yup, it is actual check

Comment: So if the check fails, the test fails and viceversa? thank you for the help

Comment: My pleasure! Read more about espresso matchers

Comment: Just tried it and it worked wonders, i was working all day trying to figure this out, thanks again. Would you provide me with a link with accurate information of Espresso?

Comment: Here is a cheatsheet with some useful methods from espresso https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/cheatsheet/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the instance of EditText by following.

```java
EditText et = mActivityRule.activity.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edit_message)
```

then fetch the text from the instance

```java
String text = et.text.toString()
```